# How to find element in selenium python using id and class in div

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

How to find element in selenium python using both id and class in div and then click it:

```
<div id="abc" class="xyz" style="" role="presentation"></div>
```

I am using the following code:

```
arrow = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="abc"][@class="xyz"]')
arrow.click()
```

But I am getting error as:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id=\"abc\"][@class=\"xyz\"]"}
```

Comment: Your XPath works against the HTML posted (see [demo](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/1f86fcab004898df25e13e6607fa2036)). Maybe try to add explicit wait if the element to be selected is generated dynamically by client-side script (see the [documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits))

Comment: Check if the element is inside `<frame>` or `<iframe>` tags.

Comment: Could you show us the URL and Tag you want to select?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use below:-

```
arrow = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="abc" and @class="xyz"]')
arrow.click()
```

Here in XPath **"and"** operator is being used to combine id and class together

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Using  this:    `div[@id="abc" and @class="xyz"]'`